# Como é a estrutura de projetos em python?

Tags: python, estrutura-de-dados, diretório

Gostaria de saber se existe um padrão ou boas práticas quanto ao jeito de estruturar um projeto em Python. Por exemplo, vou fazer um *CRUD* usando o MVC. Algo bem simples. No JAVA eu criaria uma pasta *model*, uma *controller* e uma view. Em python eu faco como? Crio módulos *models*, views e *controllers*? Ou crio uma estrutura de pastas? Ou de pacotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se voce vai usar o python "puro" estrutre da forma que vc desejar,inclusive da forma como vc fazia na sua liguagem anterior, claro que adptando às particularidades do python. Agora... se for usar algum framework, como o django ou o flask, o ideal seria seguir as recomendações dos desenvolvedores do FW.

Sugestão de um dos membros da **Python Software Foundation** para estruturação de repositorios de projetos "pure python":

```
README.rst
LICENSE
setup.py
requirements.txt
sample/__init__.py
sample/core.py
sample/helpers.py
docs/conf.py
docs/index.rst
tests/test_basic.py
tests/test_advanced.py
```

[Veja maiores detalhes no site do autor.](https://www.kennethreitz.org/essays/repository-structure-and-python)

---

Praticas muto valorizadas na comunidade python são as recomendadas pela twelve-factor,

**[The twelve-factor app:](https://12factor.net/pt_br/)**
 
Na era moderna, software é comumente entregue como um serviço: denominados web apps, ou software-como-serviço. A aplicação doze-fatores é uma metodologia para construir softwares-como-serviço que:

- Usam formatos declarativos para automatizar a configuração inicial, minimizar tempo e custo para novos desenvolvedores participarem do projeto;
- Tem um contrato claro com o sistema operacional que o suporta, oferecendo portabilidade máxima entre ambientes que o executem;
- São adequados para implantação em modernas plataformas em nuvem, evitando a necessidade por servidores e administração do sistema;
- Minimizam a divergência entre desenvolvimento e produção, permitindo a implantação contínua para máxima agilidade;
- E podem escalar sem significativas mudanças em ferramentas, arquiteturas, ou práticas de desenvolvimento.
  A metodologia doze-fatores pode ser aplicada a aplicações escritas em qualquer linguagem de programação, e que utilizem qualquer combinação de serviços de suportes (banco de dados, filas, cache de memória, etc).

Answer (score 4):

Não sei se existe um padrão para este tipo de divisão, até consultei a PEP mas não encontrei nada relacionado.
Mas segue o padrão que eu uso para construir meus projetos, baseado nesse artigo([Filesystem structure of a Python project](http://as.ynchrono.us/2007/12/filesystem-structure-of-python-project_21.html) ):

```
Projeto/
     NOME/
        __init__.py
        controllers/
            __init__.py
        views/
            __init__.py
        models/
            __init__.py         
     bin/
     docs/
     setup.py
     testes/
         NOME_testes.py
         __init__.py
```

Você pode se basear também pela estrutura de alguns projetos maiores, segue a estrutura do Django ([Esqueleto Django Project](http://django-project-skeleton.readthedocs.io/en/latest/structure.html))

```
[projectname]/                  <- project root
+-- [projectname]/              <- Django root
¦   +-- __init__.py
¦   +-- settings/
¦   ¦   +-- common.py
¦   ¦   +-- dev.py
¦   ¦   +-- djangodefault.py
¦   ¦   +-- __init__.py
¦   ¦   +-- production.py
¦   +-- urls.py
¦   +-- wsgi.py
+-- apps/
¦   +-- __init__.py
+-- configs/
¦   +-- apache2_vhost.sample
¦   +-- README
+-- doc/
¦   +-- Makefile
¦   +-- source/
¦       +-- *snap*
+-- manage.py
+-- README.rst
+-- run/
¦   +-- media/
¦   ¦   +-- README
¦   +-- README
¦   +-- static/
¦       +-- README
+-- static/
¦   +-- README
+-- templates/
    +-- README
```

Answer (score 2):

**Cara, eu normalmente uso uma estrutura própria.
Em um crud com interface gráfica com três tabelas: A B C eu normalmente faço:**

*Uma pasta pra A com o arquivo crud, o arquivo main py e o da interface gráfica

*Uma pasta pra B com o arquivo crud, o arquivo main py e o da interface gráfica

*Uma pasta pra C com o arquivo crud, o arquivo main py e o da interface gráfica

*Os arquivos da página inicial (o main py e o da interface gráfica) na pasta principal.

*Costuma funcionar, mas varia da interface gráfica, da linguagem SQL.*